# How to cross-compile for wayland on Lazarus? (either gtk or Qt)

Tags: cross-compiling, lazarus, wayland

I am trying to cross-compile for an STM32MP1 (arm) which cannot handle a tool-chain due to hardware limitations.
The target OS is a linux, base on Wayland.

Using Lazarus and LCL, I am trying to make a simple GUI application to work, this is, a frame with a button on it.

I installed Lazarus, through fpcupdeluxe which configured the tool-chain "mostly" correctly.

The problem at this point is that Lazarus keep trying to build for X11, linking against libraries which does not exists for Wayland (e.g. GtkPlug, GtkSocket, or directly X11 for Qt).

**How to specify Wayland while cross-compiling to Linux-arm?**

Comment: Note that if Lazarus IDE is too heavy for the target system, you can still try building with command line (`lazbuild`).

Answer (score 1):

- Use qt6 widgetset if possible since it's more wayland friendly.
- Build libQt6Pas from lcl/interfaces/qt6/cbindings (so you must install Qt6 devel stuff and qmake for arm)
- Open qt6/qtdefines.inc and comment {$DEFINE HASX11}.
  Now x11 units won't be included, and you can try to build lazarus for qt6 on your device.